# Searching records for date fails

Tags: yii2

Following code should search records for date. But whatever I click,main branch in condition will be executed,so I will get outprinting:

```
choice_date is false
```

It will be searched for records which are <=department_created_date,but never for records >=department_created_date
Any ideas,how to fix this?

Here is my RadioList

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Departments');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="departments-index">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin();
    $model = new backend\models\DepartmentsSearch();
    ?><?= $form->field($model, 'choice_date')->radioList(array(0 => 'Before', 1 => 'After'))->label('Please, choose Datesearching!'); ?>
    <p><?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Departments'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?></p>
    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute' => 'branches_branch_id',
                'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Branch'),
                'value' => function($model) {
                    if ($model->branches_branch_id) {
                        return $model->branchesBranch->branch_name;
                    } else {
                        return NULL;
                    }
                },
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter' => backend\models\Branches::getBranchList(),
                'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                ],
                'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Branch', 'id' => 'grid-Branch-search-rechtsart']
            ],
            'branchesBranch.branch_name',
            'department_name',
            [
                'attribute' => 'companies_company_id',
                'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Company'),
                'value' => function($model) {
                    if ($model->companies_company_id) {
                        return $model->companiesCompany->company_name;
                    } else {
                        return NULL;
                    }
                },
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter' => backend\models\Companies::getCompanyList(),
                'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                ],
                'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Company', 'id' => 'grid-Company-search-rechtsart']
            ],
            'department_created_date',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

and here is my searching class:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use backend\models\Departments;

class DepartmentsSearch extends Departments {

    public $choice_date;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['department_id'], 'integer'],
            [['choice_date'], 'boolean'],
            [['department_name', 'department_created_date', 'department_status', 'companies_company_id', 'branches_branch_id'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios() {

        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search($params) {
        $query = Departments::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate())
            return $dataProvider;
/*
Whatever I click in RadioList,property will be 0,so I'll get setFlash->'choice_date is false'
*/
        if ($this->choice_date == 0) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('If-branch is false', 'choce_date is false');

            $query->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'department_created_date', $this->department_created_date]);
        } else {
              Yii::$app->session->setFlash('if-branch is true', 'choice_date is true');
            $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'department_created_date', $this->department_created_date]);
        }

        $query->joinWith('companiesCompany');
        $query->joinWith('branchesBranch');

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'department_name', $this->department_name])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'companies.company_name', $this->companies_company_id])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'branches.branch_name', $this->branches_branch_id])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'department_status', $this->department_status]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }

}
```

Further ideas,how to fix this misery?
P.S.: For Bizley's help, here is an extraction of my controller:

```
class DepartmentsController extends Controller{
    public function actionIndex(){
    $searchModel = new DepartmentsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
 }
```

further methods are irrelevant,here. Why will property of date-record not be rendered in view?

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$model` in the view is `RadioForm` so the form sends this field as `RadioForm[choice_date]`.

But you are expecting `choice_date` from `DepartmentsSearch` model and this field is left empty.

Remove the `RadioForm` model, it's totally unneeded. Use `DepartmentsSearch` model in the form view.

**Update:**

*Since OP finally told that this is a GridView I can update my answer to suit him.*

There is `filterSelector` property in GridView you can use - you can set there additional jQuery selectors that will be used for filtering.

Here is updated code with comments below:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();
echo $form->field($searchModel /* 1 */, 'choice_date')->radioList([
    0 => 'Before', 1 => 'After'
], ['itemOptions' => ['class' => 'choiceRadio' /* 2 */]])->label('Please, choose Datesearching!');
ActiveForm::end(); /* 3 */ ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'filterSelector' => '.choiceRadio', /* 4 */
    // ...
```

1. This is the `$searchModel` I was talking about. You don't need any other model here.
2. You can set here any CSS class you want, it's for `filterSelector`.
3. Don't forget to close form like you did in your original code.
4. This is the selector for the radio input. Mind the notation - `.` for CSS class, `#` for CSS id.

Comment: Are you sure? Usually you initialize model in the controller so you can pass the request params to the `search` method and output the results in the view. Are you passing the parameters from the request to the `search` method?

Comment: Please improve -maybe- my controller(see above)

Comment: You are already passing `$searchModel` to the view. Just use `$searchModel` instead of `$model` for the form.

Comment: Could you give me an example.please. I unfortunately don't understand your commen t:=( P.S.: I must use model,too, 'cause it represents my radioList in view

Comment: This would be answered much faster if you could give all info at once. Anyway - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thx a lot. Ur the Greatest. My problem has been solved,finally :=)

Comment: I gave u all awards,which can be given at this plattform!!